# How to correct the Partition over certain parameter Order by date that has identical dates in this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have this query below which assigns a new column called 'session_change' as 1.
So this occurs whenever the difference between (date in current row) and (date from previous row) is greater than 30 minutes (30*60 seconds).

These are the date / epoch / session_change:

[image: Sample Output]

But I have a problem.

When there are identical dates in epoch seconds in consequent rows. It marks the last one among those identical epoch seconds as session_change if difference is greater than 30 minutes. (Identical epoch secs are records with these values 1475053048.00000)

When it changes from 1474460665.00000 to 1475053048.00000, it marks the last record as you see in the snapshot.

How to mark a session_change on the first record among those identical epoch seconds.

Thanks very much for your help.

```
SELECT *
    , CASE 
          WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date) - LAG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date)) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date) >= 30 * 60 
          THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END as session_change
FROM
  <table_name>
order by date;
```

Comment: Which DBMS is it? Oracle? Postgres? Redshift? Please tag only the DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: postgresql / redshift

Comment: There is no *first* record, unless you have another column that specifies the ordering.  You could mark *all* records, if you like.

Comment: Yes, how to automatically add row-number to these identical records and mark only first one? @gordonlinoff

Comment: @onlinetravel . . . Repeat:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no *first* row, unless a column explicitly defines the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really awful "solution", but the `select *` in your query and your output indicates there is really no other field we can leverage to determine what rows come when in cases where there is a tie.  So, all we can really do is fake out the rendering of the output:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE 
    WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date) -
      LAG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date)) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date) >= 30 * 60 
    THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END as session_change
FROM
  <table_name>
order by date, session_change desc
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Didn't think about that